# How to change or remove quote symbol in css

Tags: css, quotes, symbols

I've been trying to find the location of this symbol with firebug and other inspection tools.

You can see the symbol market in red in this screenshot. I want to remove it or at least change the color so it blends with the background.

[image: You can see the symbol market in red here]

This is the web page:
http://npmaudiovisual.com/esde/?page_id=41

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `style.css` file on line 88 you have:

```
q:before, q:after{ content: "'";}
```

which is adding the `'` character. Remove it or override it to an empty string (`content: ""`).

Answer (score 1):

*Line 88 in style.css:*

```
q:before, q:after{ content: "'";}
```

Either remove or override the declaration.

To override, add specificity to the selector:

```
q:before, q:after{ content: "'";} /* original declaration */
body q:before, body q:after{ content: "";} /* override with more specificity */
q:before, q:after{ content: ""!important;} /* override with !important */
```

Answer (score 0):

Now **just add** this css in your **stylesheet**

```
.entry_content q:before, .entry_content q:after {
    content: "";
}
```